# Eclipse:: Making an Apple App

Tags: eclipse, macos, app-store

Can one make an Apple app with using Eclipse?

If not, how can I make an iOS app for the App-Store ?

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly edit your source in eclipse.. I'm not sure whether there are any plugins for wrangling xcode projects, though. I imagine that'd be the big problem. Building an xcode project can easily be done from the command line, so you could run that from eclipse.

I'd say sign up for a free iOS developer account (developer.apple.com). you can develop for the iOS simulator without paying anything.. If you want to submit an app then you'll need to pay the $99 (and, of course, you'd want to be testing on actual devices beforehand!).

Xcode itself is a free download via the mac AppStore.

there are tons of good tutorials etc out there.. For a starter, I'd recommend http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

If you don't have a mac, then, ahh, I have no idea :)